# Moving a jquery div with container

Tags: jquery, html, css

As i am working on one games project in which i got small problem with the jquery slider panel. As the slider comes above the games container div. As i don't want like this. Means when i click on open slider button it should move the entire div below it. Means the slider panel div comes on the other container div. Can anyone suggest me. Please see this link for better understanding of issue. http://www.toonkaboom.com/ (Please click on the top slider panel for seeing the issue.)

Regards,
phphunger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your #toppanel slider element is positioned absolutely, it won't affect other elements because it isn't part of the flow.

What is the reason for the div that wraps it with inline styles? Get rid of that if possible and remove the position: absolute; property from the CSS on #toppanel.

This will do what you are after, however it will now affect those elements below it before you slide, so you may want to give the next div a negative margin-top value to move it back up to where it was before.

Comment: Hi Tjkoopa, thanks for your information. but the problem is it adds some extra space before the div. and adds extra space at right side also..please see this link http://www.toon10.com/

Comment: Yup, get rid of that container you have wrapping it with inline CSS setting width and floating it to the left. To shift it back up you could use a negative margin-top on the div containing the logo/menu